What Python libraries are installed with ArcGIS Desktop 10.x
Does Esri provide a comprehensive list of Python libraries packaged and installed with ArcGIS Desktop 10.x (in particular, ArcGIS 10.8)?
I've found the ArcGIS Pro documentation of Available Python libraries, but have not found a similar document for ArcGIS Desktop 10.8
The best document I've found is this blurb under Software Requirements:

ArcGIS requires Python 2.7.18 and Numerical Python 1.16.6 to be
installed. If the ArcGIS setup does not find either Python 2.7.18 or
Numerical Python (NumPy) 1.16.6 installed on the target computer,
Python 2.7.18 and Numerical Python 1.16.6 will be installed during a
complete installation.


Open IDLE either by typing idle at the Windows start menu or by clicking here:  "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\Lib\idlelib\idle.py" or open a Python window in ArcGIS 10.x
Then enter
>>>help ("modules")

Here is a portion of what was returned for me in IDLE 2.7.16 Shell
>>> help ("modules")

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...


Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 137
    warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The matplotlib.delaunay module was deprecated in version 1.4. Use matplotlib.tri.Triangulation instead.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\pkgutil.py", line 107
    __import__(name)
FutureWarning: The pandas.rpy module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. We refer to external packages like rpy2. 
See here for a guide on how to port your code to rpy2: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html
AddGeometryAttributes PixarImagePlugin    asyncore            nt
ArgImagePlugin      PngImagePlugin      atexit              ntpath
AutoComplete        PointToLine         audiodev            nturl2path
AutoCompleteWindow  PpmImagePlugin      audioop             numbers
AutoExpand          PsdImagePlugin      base64              numpy
BaseHTTPServer      PyParse             bdb                 opcode
Bastion             PyShell             binascii            operator
BatchDefineSR       Queue               binhex              optparse
BatchProject        RasterConversion    bisect              os
BatchPyramids       RemoteDebugger      bsddb               os2emxpath
BatchStats          RemoteObjectBrowser builtins            pandas
BdfFontFile         ReplaceDialog       bz2                 parser
Bindings            RstripExtension     cPickle             past
BmpImagePlugin      SSCube              cProfile            pdb
BufrStubImagePlugin SSCubeObject        cStringIO           phototopoint
CGIHTTPServer       SSCubeUtilities     calendar            pickle
CalculateAreas      SSDataObject        cgi                 pickletools
CalculateDistanceBand SSPanel             cgitb               pip
CalculateEndDate    SSPanelObject       chunk               pipes
CallTipWindow       SSReport            cmath               pkg_resources
CallTips            SSReportXML         cmd                 pkgutil
Canvas              SSTimeUtilities     code                platform
CentralFeature      SSUtilities         codecs              plistlib
ClassBrowser        SWM2Table           codeop              popen2
CodeContext         ScriptBinding       collections         poplib
CollectEvents       ScrolledList        colorsys            posixfile
ColorDelegator      ScrolledText        commands            posixpath
CompressFileGeodatabaseData SearchDialog        compileall          pprint


This was a great idea of how to show all modules that are installed

I don't believe there is a documented comprehensive list, because simply, the Python requirements for ArcMap 10.8 were:

Python 2.7.16
NumPy 1.9.3
matplotlib 1.5.2**  (might only be a server requirement)

Yes, Python came with the installer and was laid down, but you could make use of your own Python as long as you met those requirements. After that you could pip install whatever you wanted.
reference: https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/faq-what-version-of-python-is-used-in-arcgis-000013224

Thank you, I found that article after posting and came to the same conclusion but was hoping there might have been a more definitive answer
